# Unknown errors with java sorting gui

Tags: java, arrays, swing, algorithm, random

I'm not long programming and have a problem with unknown errors.
I've built a gui for testing sorting algorithms but keep getting errors and I can't see where the problem is

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SorterTool2 extends JFrame{

// Instance Variables
private JButton jbtBubble, jbtSelection, jbtInsertion;
private JLabel jlblSelect, jlblBubbleTime1, jlblBubbleTime2,
    jlblSelectionTime1, jlblSelectionTime2, jlblInsertion1,
    jlblInsertion2;
private JTextField jtfBubbleField1, jtfBubbleField2, jtfSelectField1,
    jtfSelectField2, jtfInsertionField1, jtfInsertionField2;
private JPanel content, topPanel, midPanel1, midPanel2, bottomPanel;
private JComboBox jCombo;

Random randNum = new Random();
//private int max = 5000;
private int[] myArray;
long timerStart;
long timerStop;

ListenerClass changes = new ListenerClass();

public SorterTool2() {

//Panels
  content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 0));
  topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  midPanel1 = new JPanel();
  midPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 15, 5));
  midPanel2 = new JPanel();
  midPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 15, 5));
  bottomPanel = new JPanel();
  bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 30, 5));

  add(content);

  content.add(topPanel);
  content.add(midPanel1);
  content.add(midPanel2);
  content.add(bottomPanel);
  midPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory
        .createTitledBorder("Sorted Array Analysis"));
  midPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory
        .createTitledBorder("Unsorted Array Analysis"));

// Parts for the panels
  jlblSelect = new JLabel(
        "Please select the number of elements for the array");
  jlblBubbleTime1 = new JLabel("Bubble sort in milliseconds");
  jlblBubbleTime2 = new JLabel("Bubble sort in milliseconds");
  jlblSelectionTime1 = new JLabel("Selection sort in milliseconds");
  jlblSelectionTime2 = new JLabel("Selection sort in milliseconds");
  jlblInsertion1 = new JLabel("Insertion sort in milliseconds");
  jlblInsertion2 = new JLabel("Insertion sort in milliseconds");

// Textfields
  jtfBubbleField1 = new JTextField(4);
  jtfBubbleField2 = new JTextField(4);
  jtfSelectField1 = new JTextField(4);
  jtfSelectField2 = new JTextField(4);
  jtfInsertionField1 = new JTextField(4);
  jtfInsertionField2 = new JTextField(4);

  String[] numbers = {"100", "1000", "10000"};
  jCombo = new JComboBox(numbers);
  int test = (Integer)jCombo.getSelectedItem();

//create the list
  for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
        //random numbers from 1 to max number:
     myArray[i] = randNum.nextInt(30) + 1;
  }

// Add elements
  topPanel.add(jCombo);
  topPanel.add(jlblSelect);
  midPanel1.add(jlblBubbleTime1);
  midPanel1.add(jlblSelectionTime1);
  midPanel1.add(jlblInsertion1);
  midPanel1.add(jtfBubbleField1);
  midPanel1.add(jtfSelectField1);
  midPanel1.add(jtfInsertionField1);

  midPanel2.add(jlblBubbleTime2);
  midPanel2.add(jlblSelectionTime2);
  midPanel2.add(jlblInsertion2);
  midPanel2.add(jtfBubbleField2);
  midPanel2.add(jtfSelectField2);
  midPanel2.add(jtfInsertionField2);

// Buttons
  jbtBubble = new JButton("Bubble");
  jbtSelection = new JButton("Selection");
  jbtInsertion = new JButton("Insertion");
  bottomPanel.add(jbtBubble);
  bottomPanel.add(jbtSelection);
  bottomPanel.add(jbtInsertion);

// The Bubble sort button
  jbtBubble.addActionListener(changes);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SorterTool2 frame = new SorterTool2();
  frame.setTitle("Sorter Tool");
  frame.pack();
  frame.setSize(550, 300);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

class ListenerClass implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // The iteration through the array
    // and the check value loop below it
     for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length - i - 1; j++) {

           if (myArray[j] > myArray[j + 1]) {
            // The swap method if the index
            // value is smaller
              int temp = myArray[j + 1];
              myArray[j + 1] = myArray[j];
              myArray[j] = temp;

           }
        }
     }

     jtfBubbleField2.setText(String.valueOf(1000));
  }

  }
  }
```

Could someone please have a try running this and see where I am going wrong?
I have only the bubblesort algorithm in just now and if i can get that working I can add the other 2 sorters. I think it might have something to do with the numbers being called from the JComboBox.

This would be very much appreciated as I have spent hours on this. The GUI I had completed in a couple of hours.

Thank you so much.

Comment: if you do not even know what the error you think it is how do you think someone can read your mind and tell what you are intending, this is extremely off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleaned up all of your syntax errors.  I did not try to make any of the GUI buttons work correctly.

1. You **must always** start a Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  This puts the creation and updating of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. Your JFrame method calls **must be** in a certain order.  I rearranged the JFrame method calls to be in that order.
3. If an Integer is represented as a String, you have to convert the String to an Integer.  I used the Integer valueOf static method to do the conversion.
4. When you create an array, you have to tell the Java compiler how many elements the array contains.

Here's the cleaned up code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SorterTool2 implements Runnable {

    // Instance Variables
    private JButton jbtBubble, jbtSelection, jbtInsertion;
    private JLabel jlblSelect, jlblBubbleTime1, jlblBubbleTime2,
            jlblSelectionTime1, jlblSelectionTime2, jlblInsertion1,
            jlblInsertion2;
    private JTextField jtfBubbleField1, jtfBubbleField2, jtfSelectField1,
            jtfSelectField2, jtfInsertionField1, jtfInsertionField2;
    private JPanel content, topPanel, midPanel1, midPanel2, bottomPanel;
    private JComboBox<String> jCombo;

    private Random randNum = new Random();
    // private int max = 5000;
    private int[] myArray;
    // private long timerStart;
    // private long timerStop;

    private ListenerClass changes = new ListenerClass();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Sorter Tool");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Panels
        content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 0));
        topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        midPanel1 = new JPanel();
        midPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 15, 5));
        midPanel2 = new JPanel();
        midPanel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3, 15, 5));
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3, 30, 5));

        frame.add(content);

        content.add(topPanel);
        content.add(midPanel1);
        content.add(midPanel2);
        content.add(bottomPanel);
        midPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Sorted Array Analysis"));
        midPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Unsorted Array Analysis"));

        // Parts for the panels
        jlblSelect = new JLabel(
                "Please select the number of elements for the array");
        jlblBubbleTime1 = new JLabel("Bubble sort in milliseconds");
        jlblBubbleTime2 = new JLabel("Bubble sort in milliseconds");
        jlblSelectionTime1 = new JLabel("Selection sort in milliseconds");
        jlblSelectionTime2 = new JLabel("Selection sort in milliseconds");
        jlblInsertion1 = new JLabel("Insertion sort in milliseconds");
        jlblInsertion2 = new JLabel("Insertion sort in milliseconds");

        // Textfields
        jtfBubbleField1 = new JTextField(4);
        jtfBubbleField2 = new JTextField(4);
        jtfSelectField1 = new JTextField(4);
        jtfSelectField2 = new JTextField(4);
        jtfInsertionField1 = new JTextField(4);
        jtfInsertionField2 = new JTextField(4);

        String[] numbers = { "100", "1000", "10000" };
        jCombo = new JComboBox<String>(numbers);
        int test = Integer.valueOf(jCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

        // create the list
        myArray = new int[test];
        for (int i = 0; i < test; i++) {
            // random numbers from 1 to max number:
            myArray[i] = randNum.nextInt(30) + 1;
        }

        // Add elements
        topPanel.add(jCombo);
        topPanel.add(jlblSelect);
        midPanel1.add(jlblBubbleTime1);
        midPanel1.add(jlblSelectionTime1);
        midPanel1.add(jlblInsertion1);
        midPanel1.add(jtfBubbleField1);
        midPanel1.add(jtfSelectField1);
        midPanel1.add(jtfInsertionField1);

        midPanel2.add(jlblBubbleTime2);
        midPanel2.add(jlblSelectionTime2);
        midPanel2.add(jlblInsertion2);
        midPanel2.add(jtfBubbleField2);
        midPanel2.add(jtfSelectField2);
        midPanel2.add(jtfInsertionField2);

        // Buttons
        jbtBubble = new JButton("Bubble");
        jbtSelection = new JButton("Selection");
        jbtInsertion = new JButton("Insertion");
        bottomPanel.add(jbtBubble);
        bottomPanel.add(jbtSelection);
        bottomPanel.add(jbtInsertion);

        // The Bubble sort button
        jbtBubble.addActionListener(changes);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SorterTool2());
    }

    class ListenerClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // The iteration through the array
            // and the check value loop below it
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length - i - 1; j++) {

                    if (myArray[j] > myArray[j + 1]) {
                        // The swap method if the index
                        // value is smaller
                        int temp = myArray[j + 1];
                        myArray[j + 1] = myArray[j];
                        myArray[j] = temp;

                    }
                }
            }

            jtfBubbleField2.setText(String.valueOf(1000));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks Gilbert, I think I can work away on this now. The problem was that the GUI was running ok but when I tried to choose a selection from the JComboBox to give the random number an amount it was giving me a string to int error. Sorry if i never made that clear, I sahll be careful using stackoverflow in the future, Thank you again for your great advice on swing building in order, we were not told that was important.